# Is there any way to show gmail editable html message content in gmail add-ons card?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am developing gmail add-ons, the idea is that a user opens an email, clicks the addon button and will be prompted with a question if they want to forward this email. When the user confirms, the email is forwarded with headers and everything to a configurable email address.

I want to edit the message body in gmail add-ons card. Body can be plain text or html. Plain text is showing but html preview is not showing.

I want to show editable html email content in gmail add-ons card same as it is showing when you click on forward email.

Thanks in advance.

```
var accessToken = event.messageMetadata.accessToken;
var messageId = event.messageMetadata.messageId;
GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
var message =  GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

var messageBody = message.getBody();

var messageInput = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setFieldName('message_field')
  .setTitle('Message')
  .setMultiline(true)
  .setValue(messageBody);

  section.addWidget(messageInput);
```

Comment: And? What's the problem? Where's your attempt?

Comment: I have shown email message in card in text input. but i want to show message in editable html view.

Comment: I am using newTextInput widget to show message body, and it is showing message content in plain text. But i want to show message content in html view same as it is showing in gmail.

Comment: That widget ([`CardService#TextInput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input)) is for text, not HTML. The read-only [`TextParagraph`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-paragraph) supports basic HTML **display**. So you must use a different approach.

Comment: TextParagraph support only basic tags, I want to show editable html so which approach or service will be helpful for me ?

Comment: Your own website

Comment: No, any email which has html. like this http://prntscr.com/mc2gpp

Comment: You can't do that in `CardService` currently. So you need to use your own website if you want to show all kinds of HTML content.